# triggerzone reads the same object every frame

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Trigger-zone reads the same object every frame, it is not supposed to do that and it is messing up the game. It does not happen all the time and I don't know why
Sorry for the messy code, I am not too organized. 
There are not many comments (if any) I always forget to put them in. 
I am just typing now to try to get it to let me post

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class spacereader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int spacesmoved = 0, jiff;


    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {
        sharedscript.nummoved = spacesmoved;
        if(sharedscript.reset)
        {
        spacesmoved = 0;
        jiff = 0;
        }
    }

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    Debug.Log(other.tag);
    Debug.Log(other.name);
    StartCoroutine(spotchecker(other));
    if (jiff != 2)
        jiff++;
    else if (sharedscript.ismoving)
    {
        spacesmoved++;
    }

}

private IEnumerator spotchecker(Collider other)
{
    switch (other.tag)
    {
        case "GO":

            break;
        case "MEDAVE":

            break;
        case "CHEST":

            break;
        case "BALAVE":

            break;
        case "INCOME":

            break;
        case "READING":

            break;
        case "ORIENTAL AVE":

            break;
        case "CHANCE":

            break;
        case "VERMONT":

            break;
        case "CONNAVE":

            break;
        case "INJAIL":

            break;
        case "CHARPLACE":

            break;
        case "COMPANY":

            break;
        case "STATESAVE":

            break;
        case "VIRGAVE":

            break;
        case "PENNRAIL":

            break;
        case "JAMESPLACE":

            break;
        case "TENNAVE":

            break;
        case "NEWYORKAVE":

            break;
        case "FREEPARK":

            break;
        case "KENAVE":

            break;
        case "INDIAVE":

            break;
        case "ILLAVE":

            break;
        case "BORAIL":

            break;
        case "ATLAAVE":

            break;
        case "VENTAVE":

            break;
        case "WATERWORKS":

            break;
        case "MARVGARD":

            break;
        case "GOTOJAIL":

            break;
        case "PACAVE":

            break;
        case "NORTHAVE":

            break;
        case "PENNAVE":

            break;
        case "SHORTLINE":

            break;
        case "PARKPLACE":

            break;
        case "BOARDWALK":

            break;
        case "LUXTAX":

            break;
        }
        yield return other;
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playercontroller : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> targets;
    public float speed, step;
    bool canmove = false;
    public List<Camera> cameras;
    public Camera diecam;
    public List<GameObject> players;
    public List<GameObject> playerreaders;
    public int[] turntarget = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    public int turn = 1;
    int lastturn = 0;
    bool switchit = true;
    Coroutine inin;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(canmove)
        {
            if(!switchit || sharedscript.doubles)
            {
                foreach(GameObject s in playerreaders)
                {
                    s.SetActive(false);
                }
                foreach (Camera s in cameras)
                {
                    s.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                }
                foreach(GameObject s in players)
                {
                    Collider g = s.GetComponent<Collider>();
                    g.enabled = false;
                    Rigidbody w = s.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
                    w.isKinematic = true;
                }
                lastturn = turn;
                switchit = true;
            }
            Collider d = players[turn].GetComponent<Collider>();
            d.enabled = true;
            Rigidbody f = players[turn].GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            f.isKinematic = false;
            playerreaders[turn].SetActive(true);
            cameras[turn].gameObject.SetActive(true);
            diecam.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
            if (players[turn].transform.position.x <= targets[turntarget[turn]].transform.position.x + .003 && players[turn].transform.position.x >= targets[turntarget[turn]].transform.position.x - .003 && players[turn].transform.position.z <= targets[turntarget[turn]].transform.position.z + .03 && players[turn].transform.position.z >= targets[turntarget[turn]].transform.position.z - .03)
            {
                if (turntarget[turn] < 3)
                {
                    turntarget[turn] ++;
                    players[turn].transform.Rotate(0, 90, 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    turntarget[turn] = 0;
                }
            }

            players[turn].transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(players[turn].transform.position, targets[turntarget[turn]].transform.position, speed);
        }
        if(sharedscript.nummoved >= sharedscript.total)
        {
            canmove = false;
            sharedscript.ismoving = false;
        }
        else
        {
            canmove = true;
            sharedscript.ismoving = true;
        }
        if(sharedscript.nummoved >= sharedscript.total && sharedscript.total != 0 && sharedscript.nummoved != 0 && !sharedscript.doubles && switchit)
        {
            if (turn < 3)
                turn++;
            else
                turn = 0;
            sharedscript.reset = true;
            switchit = false;
            Debug.Log("playedturn");
            sharedscript.canroll = true;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are starting your coroutine whenever **something** enters the trigger collider. Try checking if the object that entered is the object you are looking for. If it is your player and the object is tagged "Player" you could check for that:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(other.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        StartCoroutine(YourCoroutine());
    }
}
```

Another reason could be Unity collision detection. It can be wonky at times so most of the time you are better off checking if the objects collided already.

One way to solve this issue using coroutines in particular would be to store the coroutine in a variable in your script and check if it already ran. Something like this:

```
private Coroutine coroutine;
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(coroutine == null)
    {
        coroutine = StartCoroutine(YourCoroutine());
    }
}
```

Then set the value to null in OnTriggerExit or something:

```
private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    coroutine = null;
}
```

I would recommend to also check for the tag in this implementation:

```
private Coroutine coroutine;
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(coroutine == null && other.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        coroutine = StartCoroutine(YourCoroutine());
    }
}
```

Comment: glad I could help!